# Processing LONG RAW data within cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, blob

Firstly, I know LONG RAW is deprecated/evil/awful/hard to use. I don't have control of my database's schema. :)

I currently have a program that retrieves a LONG RAW column from the database and processes it client-side. This works nicely, but what I would like to do is move this processing to the server so that I don't have to translate the processing code to different languages in different client situations.

So my current query is just

```
SELECT t.ID, t.POINTS
  FROM TBL_DATAPOINTS t
 WHERE ...etc
```

and then `t.POINTS` is processed by the client.

I've tried to move this to an Oracle procedure, but I can't work out how to convert the LONG RAW column into something I can use - preferably a VARCHAR2. If I retrieve it into a cursor, how do I process each row and then return the cursor with the processed data?

I can't do it inline:

```
OPEN curData FOR
  SELECT t.ID, t.POINTS, fnProcessData(t.POINTS)
    FROM TBL_DATAPOINTS t
   WHERE ...etc
```

because of the restriction on passing LONG RAW data to functions (I get 'illegal use of LONG datatype').

I was thinking maybe I could retrieve the raw data in the cursor, then loop through it and process each line, but I don't know how (or if) to change a cursor's structure on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of processing you need to do. With LONG RAW you are very limited as you can see.
If feasible you can store your lines in temporary table using TO_LOB() function, where your value would be accessed as BLOB column (check DBMS_LOB package).

Comment: Thank you - using TO_LOB into a temporary table has worked nicely. :)